# Use C++11 in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator on Ubuntu, and I'd like to use the new C++11 features, however they are not enabled by default.

How can I configure Qt Creator to support the new C++11 features?

Comment: if you use CMake, then QtCreator can simply get the C++11 options from the generated Makefile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

to your .pro file.

Comment: My Qt Creator is already 2.7.0 on my computer, but it didn't support C++11 until I added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`.

Comment: @sashoalm interesting, I will update my answer then.

Comment: you coud use  "CONFIG += c++11" in .pro file too