# QT Creator refuses to compile c++11 (std::thread), How to set it up?

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11, compilation

I have the same problem as sashoalm here: [Use C++11 in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510897/use-c11-in-qt-creator).
Adding the -std=c++11 Flag, as Floris Vellerman suggested, solves part of the problem, but std::thread and others are still not working.

I also tried to add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pthread
```

to my .pro file, but that didn't help either. However, using the terminal I can compile it (when I use both flags).

How do i set it up, so that QT Creator can directly compile (all) c++11 projects?

**EDIT: Details**

I'm using QT Creator 2.8.1 (QT 5.0.2) in Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit)
When I add both flags into the .pro file i get the output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

When i compile with the terminal it works just fine on that exact project.

Comment: The given answers do not work. I tested it, but just like him I could only use the terminal to compile.

Comment: @MrJonas Don't forget to (1) add `LIBS += -pthread` and (2) clean and rebuild the project. Does that help?

Comment: (1) was already added BUT I cleaned (2) the Project completely and now it works! - I didn't know that could change anything. Thanks alot!

Comment: remember to run qmake after you change pro file.